# How can I pass a void returning extension method to dynamic returning extension method?

Tags: c#, delegates, extension-methods, action, func

I want to pass an extension method that returns void as a parameter to another extension method that returns dynamic.

```
public static void AddTo(this Object entity, Object parent)
{
    parent.GetCollectionOf(entity).Add(entity);
}
public static dynamic And(this Object entity, Action method)
{
    entity.method(parent);
    return entity;
}
```

I'd like to use it something like this,

```
dynamic parent = MakeNew(parentType);    
dynamic entity = MakeNew(type).And(AddTo(parent));
```

I like to pass any void method into `And()` but still return the object it extended. I hope the dynamic return type is not problematic.

What is the syntax for this kind of thing?

Comment: Your `AddTo` method takes two parameters... one of them would presumably come from `parent`, but where do you expect the other one to come from?

Comment: @Jon hmm.. from the object that `And()` is extending. At least that's what I would like. I just don't know how to write it.

Comment: You'll need to make it an `Action<object>` parameter and call `method(entity)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you perhaps do it like this?

```
myObjects
        .Where(d => d.true == true && d.Value == 77)
        .Update(e => { e.Value = 1; e.true = false; } );
```

Use my linq carefully, it could explode at any moment ;-)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to modify properties of an object returned from a LINQ query
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="input">The source</param>
    /// <param name="updater">The action to perform.</param>
    public static TSource Update<TSource>(this TSource input, Action<TSource> updater)
    {
        if (!updater.IsNull() && !input.IsNull())
        {
            updater(input);
        }
        return input;
    }
```

To explain this fully:

```
    public DataRow DoSomething(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        //DoSomething
        return dataRow;
    }

    var query = from dataRow in myDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                where
                    Double.TryParse(dataRow["Distance"].ToString(), out distance)
                    && distance > (11) && distance <= 99
                select dataRow.Update(f => DoSomething(f));
```

Comment: oh man, now I have to remember what I was trying to do here when I asked this question haha.

Comment: @Benjamin, that's how I'd use the extension method to call another method for each result in my dataset, you can use this for anything :)  return type isn't a problem either!

Comment: I think the problem I was having in this question was not understanding how to use inheritance or polymorphism or whatever it is called. That's why I was trying to use dynamic because I was clueless. I was able to do it with dynamic if I used a wrapper object. But I think I can see now that it is not so hard to make fluent extensions.

Comment: Does that mean I can haz all teh points? Since I OBVIOUSLY pointed you in the right direction! ;-)

Comment: haha I guess why not. I can't tell what the question looks like it is about to others, but it seems like you understood my intention.

Answer (score 2):

Have I got your question right?

```
dynamic entity = MakeNew(type).And(() => 
{
  AddTo(parent); 
});
```

Comment: I think so. Let me try it out. Thanks.

Comment: `parent` is defined `dynamic parent = MakeNew(parentType)` which seems to cause "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type" when I call And().

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you *actually* want this:

```
public static void AddTo(this Object entity, Object parent)
{
    parent.GetCollectionOf(entity).Add(entity);
}

public static dynamic And(this Object entity, Action<object> method)
{
    method(entity);
    return entity;
}

dynamic entity = MakeNew(type).And(entity => entity.AddTo(parent));
```

Having said that, it's still not clear where `parent` is coming from to start with...

Comment: `parent` is also `dynamic parent = MakeNew(parentType)` which seems to give "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

Comment: @Benjamin: Ah, right. Why exactly do you need it to be dynamic? Why not just have it as `object`? Are you sure that dynamic typing is really helping you here?

Comment: I'm such a beginner that I can't tell you if `object` would produce the same results or not. I will mess around with it. I don't really understand the diff between using object and using dynamic yet.. dynamic simply sounded self explanatory to me. I will put the `MakeNew` method into the original post if it makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin: If you're a real beginner to C# I would advise *against* using `dynamic`. There are numerous subtleties to it. But fundamentally you're trying to call an extension method against a dynamic expression, which isn't going to work to start with - and then trying to use a lambda expression as the argument... basically you're doing a bunch of things which aren't supported by `dynamic`.

Comment: I think I'll drop the `And()` extension method idea then because it doesn't seem like I can make a very dynamic application using `object` - one person said you can't dynamically change an `object`. I've heard of generics but I've not found a relevant enough explanation to discern if they would allow the dynamic design I am after. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Benjamin: It depends on what you mean by "dynamically change". To be honest, if you're this new to C# I would start from scratch - and learn generics *before* dynamic typing, lambda expressions and extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think that C# is not yet "dynamic" enough to do the thing I think you want.

The And method won't work, since the `entity` parameter is of type `object`, so `entity.method(parent)` will not work. Even if you define `entity` to be of type `dynamic`, C# will try to find a method called "method" to call. You can do this in your example:

```
public static dynamic And(this Object entity, Action method, object parameter) 
{     
      method(entity, parameter);     
      return entity; 
}
```

and

```
dynamic entity = MakeNew(type).And(AddTo, parameter);
```

Comment: I had to mess around this a bit because the `method(entity, parameter)` call wouldn't take 2 parameters, but in the end it didn't like that entity was not yet defined when I tried to pass it in. I could have messed it up pretty bad though.